# How to cache function with different arguments in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

I'm using **slow data loading and calculations** and would like to **cache the results**, so next time it would be faster.

Example - we would like to have two functions 1) convert currency to USD and 2) calculate CPI-index (Consumer Price Index).

```
echo to_usd("EUR", (2000, 1, 1), false) # => 0.846
echo to_cpi("USD", (2000, 1, 1))        # => 144.0
```

I wonder if it would be possible to **auto-generate the caching code**, maybe use some library? Something like:

```
proc to_usd_slow*(currency: string, time: TimeD): float =
  1.0 # some slow calculations

proc to_usd* = cache(to_usd_slow)
```

I'm currently write cache manually, as in the code below, [playground](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2LUP):

```
import hashes, tables

proc autohash*[T: tuple|object](o: T): Hash =
  for f in o.fields: result = result !& f.hash

type
  TimeD = tuple[year, month, day: int]
  PointM = tuple[time: TimeD, value: float]

# CPI - Consumer Price Index
proc to_cpi_slow(currency: string, time: TimeD, extrapolate: bool): float =
  1.0 # some slow calculations

# Cached version ---------------------------------------------------------------
type ToCpiKey = (string, TimeD, bool)
proc hash(v: ToCpiKey): Hash = v.autohash
var to_cpi_cache = init_table[ToCpiKey, float]()

proc to_cpi*(currency: string, time: TimeD, extrapolate: bool): float =
  let key: ToCpiKey = (currency, time, extrapolate)
  if key notin to_cpi_cache:
    to_cpi_cache[key] = to_cpi_slow(currency, time, extrapolate)
  to_cpi_cache[key]

# Curency conversions ----------------------------------------------------------
proc to_usd_slow*(currency: string, time: TimeD): float =
  1.0 # some slow calculations

type ToUsdMKey = (string, TimeD)
proc hash(v: ToUsdMKey): Hash = v.autohash

var to_usd_cache = init_table[ToUsdMKey, float]()
proc to_usd*(currency: string, time: TimeD): float =
  let key: ToUsdMKey = (currency, time)
  if not(key in to_usd_cache): to_usd_cache[key] = to_usd_slow(currency, time)
  to_usd_cache[key]

# Usage ------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo to_cpi("USD", (2000, 1, 1), false)
echo to_usd("EUR", (2000, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to generate caching code using macros, most likely you want to look for [macro pragmas](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#userminusdefined-pragmas-macro-pragmas) for writing necessary boilerplate for your functions.

If you want to use the existing library you might want to look at [memo](https://github.com/andreaferretti/memo) library.